# I am creating a program to implement Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++ for Codechef. But i need a way to optimize the program for large inputs (10^9)

Tags: c++, optimization

```
#include <iostream> 
#include<map>
using namespace std;
map <long long  , long long> h;
void sieve(long long start,long long size) 
{
    long long i,j;
    for (i=2; i*i <= size; i++) {
           if (!h[i]) {
                   for(j = i+i; j < size ;j+=i) { h[j] = 1; }
           }
    }
    for (i=2; i<size; i++) {
           if (!h[i]) { printf("%lld \n", i); }
    }
}
int main() {
    long long input[2],i=0,n;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
     scanf("%lld",&input[i]);      
    sieve(input[0],input[1]);        
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem here?  It's too slow?  That's mostly the algorithm's fault.

Comment: std::map is certainly not the best choice. Perhaps the infamous std::vector<bool> would actually be useful here. Also, using scanf is a bit strange when doing C++ and iostreams. Other than that, the alogrithm is implemented very naively... I assume that is on purpose.

Comment: Could u pin point where i am being naive? I hope to learn from people on Stack Overflow

Comment: Not skipping all the even numbers in the outer loop increment is one thing I noticed.

Comment: So should i add a condition that checks i%2==0 except for when i=2(only even prime). That should eliminate the even numbers i think.

Answer (score 2):

std::map is certainly not the best choice. Perhaps the infamous std::vector would actually be useful here. Also, using scanf is a bit strange when doing C++ and iostreams. Other than that, the alogrithm is implemented very naively... I assume that is on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There are [about](http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml) 50 million primes less than 10^9.  If you try and store them in a `std::map` at probably at least 32-bytes per prime with the heap management overhead, you'll need at least 1.5GByte to store them all and actually it'll be much worse than this because your map records are massive 64-bit keys to 64-bit values.  Note also that since you only store '1' on the value side, the values contain no real info and a `std::set` would be a better choice.

But a far better optimisation would be to store primeness as a 10^9-bit bit-vector (`std::vector<bool>` or `boost::dynamic_bitset`) needing just 119MByte.  This will be *much* faster to scan and update than your `std::map` or a `std::set` version.

If it helps to have something to aim for, I just checked my own bit-vector based prime sieving code (used for some Project Euler problems); it will sieve to 10^9 in 11.5s on an i7, or 100s on an old 1.6GHz Pentium3 laptop.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blog.vudduu.com/2011/11/sieve-of-eratosthenes-best.html) is the best implementation. But what problem do you need to solve?
I solve this ([SPOJ - PRIME1](https://www.spoj.pl/problems/PRIME1/)) problem.